# MYSQL "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the title error when attempting to execute the following:

```
       sInsertInto = "INSERT INTO 5why (date, op_id, serial, why1, why2, why3, why4, why5, root_cause, lessons) VALUES (" + _
    "'" + f_date + "', " + _
    "'eccross', " + _
    " '" + f_partnum + "', " + _
    " '" + f_first + "', " + _
    " '" + f_second + "', " + _
    " '" + f_third + "', " + _
    " '" + f_fourth + "', " + _
    " '" + f_fifth + "', " + _
    " '" + f_root + "'" + _
    " '" + f_lessons + "'" + _
    ")"
```

The value count should be fine here; but its not for whatever reason and I cannot get this error to resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing a comma, specifically after the `f_root` line.  I would think this would be a syntax error due to the two strings `'f_root' 'f_lessons'`, but I guess not.

---

Your query is vulnerable to injection.  You should be using parameterized queries with prepared statements.  Depending upon the variable values, this may also be the problem.

Comment: This causes to values count be 9 while columns are 10.